# Firebase login react native >0.60 "auth/network-request-failed" DEBUG only IOS

Tags: firebase, react-native, debugging, upgrade, general-network-error

I recently converted all my code from react native 0.59 to 0.60.5 by simply creating a new repo and copying and pasting the new files in.  I am getting this error when I try to login with facebook or google, but the weird thing is it's only with "Debug" mode enabled.  I can't tell much behind the generic error.

```
code: "auth/network-request-failed"
message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."
```

I need to use debug mode for development, so just not using debug isn't an option.  Is there some setting on the simulator that I need to change.  I have tried resetting the device multiple times.

Comment: Did you try adding latest `SHA` debug key in firebase cosole under project settings?

Comment: @katwal-Dipak I believe SHA is only used for android.  I do have the latest key there.  I also have downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist and it is included in my build as well.